# What is the difference between card_view and app:card?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I am implementing CardView in my app and I have notice that it is working without creating a card_view using only "app:" ->

What is the difference between A and B?

A:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            >
```

B:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no important difference. Both `app` and `card_view` are namespace declarations, and both use the same namespace:   `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.
It's worth to mention that in A case you import the `app` namespace earlier in XML declaration and in case B you import it right in `CardView` tag